# Не понимаю знаков - не понимаю смысла (см.). Поможете?

Tags: пунктуация

> Христианская базилика сохранила традиционное, продольное построение.
>   Вдоль главной оси её прямоугольника, отрезанные протяжёнными рядами
>   колонн, симметрично – по сторонам от основного пространства или
>   главного нефа, лежат малые. По коротким сторонам располагаются: вход,
>   а напротив – обширная апсида – полуциркульная ниша, обычно перекрытая
>   полукуполом – конхой.

Кто - малый - лежит?

Что делать с изобилием тире?!

Comment: Нефы лежат — кто же ещё? Это же базилика.

Comment: Давай ответ, я запуталась! Со всей пунктуацией! "Или  главного нефа" надо как-то выделять (тогда)?

Comment: Ответ я дать не могу. Я догадался, что "малые" — это меньшие нефы, расположенные симметрично по сторонам от главного нефа. Авторский абзац вообще невозможно понять, кроме первого предложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Планы «типовой» базилики. Лучше один раз увидеть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Христианская базилика сохранила традиционное, продольное построение. По сторонам от основного пространства или главного нефа, отрезанные рядами высоких колонн, тянутся малые (северный и южный) нефы. Строго напротив входа, вдали, — обычно перекрытая полукуполом-конхой широкая полуциркульная ниша — апсида.

Comment: У ти мой залатой! )))

Comment: А вот интересуюсь: Нартекс, Наос и Трансепт - они как, на личико ничего? Деамбулаторий - фи, гадость какая... а Апсида - девица, што с ёй взять?

Comment: Это всё, включая средокрестие, из следующей Вашей книжки — о романском храме.

Comment: Готовились тексты для авторского сайта - где было всё: и про мужей, и про детей, и про дельфинов, и про актёрскую карьеру. С картинками и видео: автор - лицо публичное. И вдруг посередь дороги объявился издатель - захотел именно книжку про всяки римски дела. Мы всё бросили - и хвать одновременно писать и править, кусманами. Потому всё такое сырое и я не вчиталась...